# Testing a simple guard clause in isolation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I’m using decorator objects in a Rails app so that I don’t have to do `nil?` checks in views. Everything is working nicely and it’s easy to test, but I’m suspicious that my test:code ratio is a little high. Am I being too verbose? Is there a better way this could be done?

*Test suite*:

```
# spec/decorators/client_decorator_spec.rb
require_relative "../../app/decorators/client_decorator"

describe ClientDecorator do
  describe ".position" do
    context "with a recorded client position" do
      it "returns the name of the position" do
        occupation = double("Occupation", name: "CEO")
        client = double("Client", occupation: occupation)
        expect(ClientDecorator.new(client).position).to eq "CEO"
      end
    end

    context "with no recorded position" do
      it "returns an empty string" do
        client = double("Client", occupation: nil)
        expect(ClientDecorator.new(client).position).to eq ""
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*Production code*:

```
# app/decorators/client_decorator.rb
require "simple_decorator"

class ClientDecorator < SimpleDecorator
  def position
    return "" unless occupation
    occupation.name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the code/test ratio is probably a little high - especially if you have to do this for many attributes.

May I direct your attention to [the `#try` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try)? Seems to me you that you might be able to skip *a lot* of code (and tests) by doing things like `@client.try(:occupation).try(:name)`.

`#try` simply returns `nil` if the receiver doesn't respond to the whatever message you're sending. And since `#try` is also implemented on the `nil` object, you can chain "tries" together.

In you views, writing something like `<%= @client.try(:occupation).try(:name) %>` will just print nothing if the `try`-chain ends up returning `nil` - same as your current setup. And if you want a different fallback, you can do this:

```
<%= @client.try(:occupation).try(:name) || "N/A" %>
```

In other words, having an entire decorator seems a bit much just to absorb `nil`s. But granted, the view ends up having to dig a bit further into the models.

You can of course also keep the decorator (at least so you current code doesn't break elsewhere), but simply rewrite it using `#try` to something like

```
# app/decorators/client_decorator.rb
require "simple_decorator"

class ClientDecorator < SimpleDecorator
  def position
    occupation.try(:name) || ""
  end
end
```

which I honestly don't know if I'd bother to test very rigorously (lest it breaks horribly).

Comment: Thanks, that’s exactly what I needed. I’ll go with the latter approach; it’s nice to keep `try` out of the view. I don’t think it needs testing either.

Comment: @JezenThomas `#try` has its uses in views too, though. It's very useful if you need localization for fallback values, for instance. I'd rather handle that in a view, e.g. `<%= model.try(:foo) || t(".no_value") %>`

Comment: I think you've got the right idea that "having an entire decorator seems a bit much just to absorb `nil`s", but maybe the best suggestion is to create a base decorator that absorbs `nil` by default for all methods unless overridden? Then that could be tested once and wouldn't need to be tested for every decorator.

Comment: @Lee It's tempting, but also somewhat blunt as it could camouflage actual errors. It could work of course, but personally I usually prefer to explicitly handle `nil`s where they may be - and seeing things fail if there's a `nil` where it _shouldn't_ be.

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe that you are *that* verbose. The specs are covering the method implementation properly. Something that I would consider improving in your specs ir the repetitive parts of the code. You could DRY your spec with an approach like this:

```ruby
describe ClientDecorator do    
  describe "#position" do
    subject { decorator.position }
    let(:decorator) { ClientDecorator.new(client) }
    let(:client) { double "Client", occupation: occupation }

    context "with a recorded client position" do
      let(:occupation) { double "Occupation", name: "CEO" }
      it "returns the name of the position" do
        expect(subject).to eq "CEO"
      end
    end

    context "with no recorded position" do
      let(:occupation) { nil }
      it "returns an empty string" do
        expect(subject).to be_blank
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also take a look here about how to [describe your methods](http://betterspecs.org/#describe) (e.g. `#` for instance methods and `.` for class methods). Don't think of it of something as a *rule*, but rather than a best practise.